# How can I only get related object NSSet or can/should i use NSPredicate?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Could my below code is displaying all exercises rather than just the ones attached to the current day. Now if I use day.dayExercises and use a for loop I have access to all the necessary data the tableview requires however I am not sure on how to changed the fetchrequest to use objects within the relationship day.dayexercises.

```
class ExercisesTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

var dayExercises:[Exercises] = []
var day:Days!
var fetchResultController:NSFetchedResultsController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = "\(day.day)"

    // print(day.dayExercises)

    for item in day.dayExercises{
        print(item)
    }

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Exercises")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext {

        fetchResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        fetchResultController.delegate = self

        do {
            try fetchResultController.performFetch()
            dayExercises = fetchResultController.fetchedObjects as! [Exercises]
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

**print(item) outputs the following:**

```
<Gym_Notes.Exercises: 0x12e66d4d0> (entity: Exercises; id: 0xd000000000080004 <x-coredata://XXXXX-D879-XXXX-9DE7-7AXX14XXX623/Exercises/p2> ; data: {
exerciseDay = "0xd000000000040002 <x-coredata://79XX0B7D-XX79-43XX-9DE7-7A26XXXX2623/Days/p1>";
image = <89504e47 0d0a1a0a 0000000d 49484452 00000080 00000080 08060000 00c33e61 cb000000 01735247 4200aece 1ce90000 0009>;
    name = Bob;
    reps = Bob;
    rest = Bob;
    sets = Bob;
    weight = Bob;
})
```

Comment: Why don't you use `day. dayExercises`?

Comment: @user1941284 because further down within my cellForRowAtIndex function if I use let exercise = day.dayExercises[indexPath.row] i get Type NSSet has no subscript members. Do i not need to edit the managedObjectContext constant to use the relationship objects of day and/or edit the fetchRequest as it's currently getting all objects/records from Exercises.

Comment: try like this `if let exercise = day.dayExercises?[indexPath.row] as? Exercise {`